# Itextsharp PdfReader is slow

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating an application that has to generate thousands of PDF files at a time.  I am using ITextSharp to do this and it seems that the PdfReader is slowing down the process.  Below is my code.

```
using (MemoryStream foutput = new MemoryStream())  
{
    using (PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(templateByteArray)) // slow
     {
          using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdf, foutput))
          {
               AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
               form.SetField(_dic[@"1,1"], "some string1");
               form.SetField(_dic[@"1,2"], "some string2");
               stamper.FormFlattening = true;
           }
           pdf.RemoveUsageRights();
      }
      EnqueueFile(foutput.ToArray());
}
```

I have a separate consumer thread that takes every byte array and writes the PDF documents to the HDD from a queue.  After I messed around with the code, it seems that the bottleneck is in the PdfReader class.  Is there an alternate way to doing what I am trying to do or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue, filling in some forms and flattening them. I profiled the program and PdfStampler.Close and get_AcroFields are the slowest. Using FieldCache doesn't make any difference in my case. Did you end up using itext 7? Thanks

Comment: I converted my program to itext 7 and it is slower! I would appreciate if you could share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the properties of the fields `_dic[@"1,1"]` and `_dic[@"1,1"]` over and over again. You should cache those properties. In Java, that's done like this:

```
HashMap<String,TextField> fieldCache = new HashMap<String,TextField>();
```

This cache stores information about each `TextField` that is encountered. You introduce it with the `setFieldCache()` method:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest,
    HashMap<String,TextField> cache, String name, String login)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    form.setFieldCache(cache);
    form.setField("test", "test");
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

The first time the field with name `"test"` is encountered, the information will be read from the existing file. The next time it is encountered, the `TextField` info will be retrieved from the cache instead of from the existing file.

Comment: Thank you. That helped, but not that much. The bulk of the time spent is still when the PdfReader is reading the byte array.  Is there anyway that I could execute the PdfReader only once then use that reader to write multiple PDF documents? Just to not have to wait for the reader to read the template file over and over again every time.

Comment: There is no way to reuse `PdfReader` if you're using the `reader` instance in the context of `PdfStamper` because `PdfStamper` alters the structure of the PDF. You could try to [read the PDF partially](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#262-memoryinfo.java)), but since the full PDF is needed anyway, I don't think this will matter much. If the performance of iText 5 isn't sufficient for you, you should switch to [iText 7](http://itextpdf.com/blog/itext-7-and-itext-5-roadmaps-differences-updates). iText 7 is faster than iText 5, especially the reader.

Comment: I will give iText 7 a shot.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: In my case setting the FieldCache didn't make any difference. I use iTextSharp 5.5.10. I will give iText 7 a try...